# cannot find particular movie in a list vue and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am trying to get the details of a particular movie in a list of movies but it cannot get the particular id.

here is my Vue component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <el-row :gutter="10">
            <el-col :span="6" v-for="movie in movies" v-bind:key="movie">
                <el-card shadow="always" :body-style="{ padding: '0px'} ">
                    <img v-bind:src="movie.cover_photo" class="image">
                    <div style="padding: 14px;">
                        <div class="bottom clearfix">
                            <a href="#" @click="showMovie(movie.id)">{{movie.title}}</a>
                            <h4>{{ movie.year }}</h4>
                            <h4>{{ movie.type }}</h4>

                        </div>
                        <div class="block">

                            <el-rate v-model="value1" :max="10"></el-rate>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </el-card>
            </el-col>

        </el-row>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                movies: [],
                movie: {
                    id: '',
                }

            };
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchMovieList();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchMovieList() {
                axios.get('/movies').then(response => {
                    this.movies = response.data;
                })

                    .catch(error => console.log(error))

            },
            showMovie(id) {
                axios.get('/movies/' + id).then((res) => {

                    if (res.data.status == true) {
                        this.movie = res.data.movie;
                        console.log(res.data.movie)
                    } else {
                        alert('No Movie founded with this id')
                    }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    alert('error')
                })
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .image {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

my show method:

```
     public function show($id)
    {
    $movie=Movie::find($id);
    if($movie){
    return response()->json(['status'=>true,'movie'=>$movie]);
    }else{
    return response()->json(['status'=>false]);
    }
    }
```

and my route:

```php
Route::get('/movies/{id}', 'MoviesController@show');
```

It cannot find the movie with the particular id. What could be wrong? When I visit the API URL directly on the browser and directly type the route I get the particular movie I want.

Comment: You should try to debug it in your browser (press F12) and see which request it is doing and if it actually returns what you want. Also the `res.data.status` check you are doing is a bit out of place. You should not need to check for errors when your response code is 200.

Comment: i get status code okay checked on the network tab on the console i dont know what could be wrong

Comment: its hard to tell. Your `show` method returns a view, while it should probably return a JSON model like `return response()->json($movie)`.

Comment: in order to use results in component with axios you need to return your data as json not to blade as array. ps: if your app sends data from blade to component then you need to pass prop from component tag which I don't see any prop in your script, either way your data should return as json.

Comment: i edited my show function check out the code @mafortis

Comment: @kadzokanene now change your movie to null object `movie: '',` otherwise with your current code you have to use push and only can pass id of your movie

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would resolve all your issues but you could try the following:

```php
Route::get('/movies/{movie}', 'MoviesController@show');
```

```php
public function show(Movie $movie)
{
    return view('details', ['movie' => $movie]);
}
```

Also, the naming convention for controllers is to use the model name in its singular form. Your controller should therefore be named `MovieController` without `s`.

Another thing, in your view component you should include the movie_id in the url otherwise Laravel has no way to know which movie you're trying to fetch:

```php
...
axios.get('/movies/1')
...
```